# USB external harddrive not being recognised

Tags: macos, hard-drive, external-disk

My WD 2 TB hard drive has suddenly stopped being recognized by my MacBook Pro, running OS X 10.11.3, but it's working on my ThinkPad, running Windows 7 and Linux Mint. The solution I found was to reformat the drive. However, I cannot do that as I do not have a place to copy all the files on the HD to.

I've had a similar issue before in Windows 7. I went to some part of the Registry and deleted the records pertaining to the USB drive and it worked fine after that.

Is there any similar solution like that in OS X?

The output for 'diskutil list':

```
$ diskutil list
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *251.0 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:          Apple_CoreStorage Macintosh HD            250.1 GB   disk0s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk0s3
/dev/disk1 (internal, virtual):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                  Apple_HFS Macintosh HD           +249.8 GB   disk1
                                 Logical Volume on disk0s2
                                 3D4D9C68-75DA-41A9-BCF7-54D66F542074
                                 Unencrypted
/dev/disk2 (external, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:     FDisk_partition_scheme                        *2.0 TB     disk2
   1:               Windows_NTFS Elements                2.0 TB     disk2s1
```

Screenshot of "Get Info":
[image: Get info of USB drive]

Comment: Can you post the information provided by `diskutil list` from the Terminal (found at `/Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app`)? This should list the disks that your system registers.

Comment: Now it being recognised but I am unable to copy files into it.
In Get info, Sharing & Permissions: You can only read.

Comment: @perhapsmaybeharry As I have crossed the word limit for the sharing the output, I have edited it to the message.

Comment: unrelated question: How do I format my terminal output?

Comment: @qbektrix to get a box like visible now, prepend 4 x space on every new line

Comment: @qbektrix Alternatively, you can select text and press the `{}` button in the question toolbar. It's easier if you need to format many lines of code

Comment: @qbektrix to circumnavigate the "you can only read" error, open Get Info, click the lock at the bottom left, select your username in the "Sharing Permission" field and change your access to "Read and Write".

Comment: @perhapsmaybeharry I cannot find the lock. I am adding the screenshot to the main post.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look [here](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/pro-tip-enable-ntfs-write-support-natively-for-os-x/) on to enable native write support to NTFS.

Comment: I checked my username by using "whoami". Then using that I ran the command. What followed was a list of outputs like:
chown: <folder and file path>: Read-only file system
ending with...
chown: /Volumes/Elements/: Read-only file system

Problem still persist.

Comment: Oh wait, it's NTFS. NTFS isn't exactly directly editable by OS X...

Comment: Do I have any option?

Comment: Yep, edited my answer to reflect this.